# .net pdf separate CMYK plates and spot color

Tags: c#, pdf, cmyk

i need to generate separate CMYK image from a PDF.
I was able to do it using Ghostscprit with commando -sDEVICE = tiffsep, but does not work with all pdf files.
With some files throws an exception, either by c# code that commands from the prompt.
I tried with Imagemagick but does not extract individual images for spot colors.
Someone knows some other method, or library (free or paid) that can do the same in .net?

Thank you

Here you can dowloads a file with the problem:
[Example file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9u68v6uzkegniip/Omet1.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: ImageMagick uses Ghostscript so you will not get better results with that.

Comment: Do the files which fail have something in common? Such as being already set for CMYK? or NOT being CMYK?

Comment: The PDF files are CMYK. But with some of them works fine, but does not work with other. There are no particular differences that I am able to identify.

thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the pdf file and information provided on dropbox is not available anymore.